# Cannot find the CSS Errors in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, web-inspector

I'm trying to debug a website and in Chrome's inspect element I'm seeing 8 errors and 1 warning.

[image: Chrome CSS Errors & Warnings]

The Warning shows up right next to the problem.

[image: CSS warning]

However, the Errors don't show up anywhere and I can't locate them. Also, the errors and warnings show an underline when I hover over them (like links often do), but clicking on them does nothing... I'm fairly certain this is just a limitation, but I thought I'd see if something was screwed up with that too.

**Solution**

When I was hitting the console >_ icon it needed to be raised up. I mistakenly thought it was referring to the CSS, but the errors were console errors (not CSS errors).

[image: Console error collapsed & raised]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the "Show Drawer" icon (it looks like `>_`) Those errors are displayed there under the Console tab.

2023 Update:

Now the option is located in the 3-dot menu on the top right corner. Click that, then choose "Show console drawer" or just press escape like @kjw mentioned in their comment.

Comment: I feel like an idiot - you're right. I assumed the "Errors" were in the CSS, but they were referring to the console. When I clicked >_ the console area appeared below, but I didn't know to drag it up. I've attached the solution to the question with a gif too - hopefully helps anyone else as inpatient as myself.

Comment: You can also press Esc to get the console to display.  I'm a fan of keyboard shortcuts ;)

Comment: I don't see any >_ icon, either in Elements or Console in Chrome. Nor do I ever see CSS errors or warnings in Developer Tools, ever. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidSpector They've changed the UI since this post, now you can just press the escape key, or open the 3 dot menu in the top right and click "Show console drawer"